# why is my javascript style code not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, styling

here is my html code:

```
<body>
<p id="text">Change my style</p>
<div>
    <button id="jsstyles" onclick="style()">Style</button>
</div>
</body>
```

here is my javascript:

```
function style()
{
Text.style.fontSize = "14pt";
Text.style.fontFamily = "Comic Sans MS";
Text.style.color = "red";
}
```

I dont see a problem in this code and its still not working

Comment: Where do you set the variable `Text`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Not invoked or throws and error or not updating text field (because of typo)? How is your Javascript wired into HTML? You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few problem in your code

1. You need to set variable to what element you want to change in your javascript.
2. You can't name your function `style()` because the name style is already use in javascript. Instead try different name like `handleStyle()` or something else.

```js
// Set variable to what element you want to change
const Text = document.querySelector("#text");

// For this example I use handleStyle for the function
function handleStyle() {
  Text.style.fontSize = "14pt";
  Text.style.fontFamily = "Comic Sans MS";
  Text.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="text">Change my style</p>
    <div>
        <button id="jsstyles" onclick="handleStyle()">Style</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `text` not `Text`.

Or even better use `document.getElementById`.

Using [named access on the window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) is frowned upon.
[Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables/3434388#3434388)

Comment: Thank you all it was just the name of the function that needed to be changed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmer mentioned in the comment, you don't set the variable.

**More important, you can't use `style` as a `variable` or `function` name. I tried to use `style` as a `funtion` name and it produced `error` where `style` is not a `function`**

This should work:

```
<body>
<p id="text">Change my style</p>
<div>
    <button id="jsstyles" onclick="styles()">Style</button>
</div>
</body>
```

```
var Text = document.getElementById('text')
function styles()
{
Text.style.fontSize = "14pt";
Text.style.fontFamily = "Comic Sans MS";
Text.style.color = "red";
}
```